# JTable bug - First row and column cell misaligned until you click the table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have this strange bug where the cell in the first row and column in my JTable is misaligned. You can see in the image how the first cell's text is drastically misaligned.

When you click the table, the problem fixes itself.

Does anyone know why this could be occurring, or how it can be fixed? I have never had this issue with JTables before.

[image: jtable bug]

My code looks like the following. Note I have done this before but never experienced this bug.

```
 JTable table = new JTable(myTableModel);     

 TableColumnModel colModel=table.getColumnModel();
 colModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(200);
 colModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(150);
 colModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
 colModel.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);

 table.setRowHeight(26);

 JScrollPane tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
 tableScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
```

Comment: This `tableScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));` isn't going to help, you should consider using [`JTable#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize `](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(java.awt.Dimension)). Are you using a custom cell render at all? What version of Java? What OS?  What look and feel?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Don't forget to `pack()`.